# Optimization Problem / Fuel Tank

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am asked to design a fuel tank for a fighter jet that will hold $300$ liters of jet fuel. The shape of the tank is a cylinder with two hemispheres attached to each end. The side wall (the cylinder part) costs $\$\ 0.1$ per cm$^2$ to make and the rounded tops costs $\$\ 0.3$ per cm$^2$ to make. What is the optimal radius of the tube that will minimize manufacturing costs?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the volume of that shape is given by:

$$\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}+\mathcal{V}_\text{hemisphere}+\mathcal{V}_\text{hemisphere}=\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}+\mathcal{V}_\text{sphere}\tag1$$

Now, for the volume of a cylinder:

$$\mathcal{V}_\text{cylinder}=\pi\cdot\text{r}_\text{cylinder}^2\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}\tag2$$

And for the sphere:

$$\mathcal{V}_\text{sphere}=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}_\text{sphere}^3\tag3$$

Now, we also know that:

$$\text{r}=\text{r}_\text{cylinder}=\text{r}_\text{sphere}\tag4$$

So the total volume is given by:

$$\mathcal{V}=\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^3=\frac{\pi\text{r}^2}{3}\cdot\left(3\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\text{r}\right)\tag5$$

And the surface area is given by:

$$\mathcal{S}=2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\tag6$$

And for the costs we can set up a function:

$$\mathcal{K}=\text{K}_1\cdot2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+\text{K}_2\cdot4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\tag7$$

Well, you know the volume:

$$\mathcal{V}=\frac{\pi\text{r}^2}{3}\cdot\left(3\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}+4\text{r}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}=\frac{\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{r}^2}-\frac{4\text{r}}{3}\tag8$$

So, in order to minimize the costs we can write:

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{K}}{\partial\text{r}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{r}}\left\{\text{K}_1\cdot2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}\cdot\left(\frac{\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{r}^2}-\frac{4\text{r}}{3}\right)+\text{K}_2\cdot4\cdot\pi\cdot\text{r}^2\right\}=$$
$$8\text{K}_2\pi\text{r}-\frac{16\text{K}_1\pi\text{r}}{3}-\frac{2\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{\text{r}^2}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{r}=\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{\pi\text{K}_2-\frac{2\pi\text{K}_1}{3}}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\tag9$$

And so the height will be:

$$\text{h}\space_\text{cylinder}=2\cdot\left(\frac{6}{\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\text{K}_2}{\text{K}_1}-1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\text{K}_1\mathcal{V}}{3\text{K}_2-2\text{K}_1}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\tag{10}$$

> Here I assumed that $\text{K}_2>\text{K}_1$.

Comment: Very clear and well presented answer!

Comment: Just one thing, could you point out the line that you take the prices of the surface areas into account?

Comment: The "cm" actually represent centimeters. That doesn't change the answer does it? 0.2 centimeters seems pretty small for the optimal radius

Comment: @BrantClayton I edited my answer, now it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Let the radius be $r$ and the height $h$. Let the surface area of each hemisphere be $S_{h}$ and the surface area of the cylinder be $S_{c}$ and let the total surface area be $S$

$S_{c} = 2\pi r h$

$S_{h} = 2\pi r^{2}$

Then $S = 2\pi r(2r+h)$

Let the volume of each hemisphere be $V_{h}$ and the volume of the cylinder be $V_{c}$. Let the total volume be $V$

$V_{c} = \pi r^{2}h$

$V_{h} = \frac{2}{3}\pi r^{3}$

$V = \pi r^{2}(h + \frac{4r}{3})$

We wish to maximise the volume for a given surface area (so we treat the surface area as constant).

Now you should also apply the price weightings to each component of the surface area, then substitute $h$ in terms of $S$ and $r$ into $V$. Then you can differentiate $V$ with respect to $r$ to find the value of $r$ which gives the maximum value of $V$

Answer (score 0):

I too would be brief  about solution ... (if you care to learn Lagrange multiplier more powerful approach) with 2 functions $ (V,A) $  and two variables $ (r,h)$  ; k= Ratio of costs Cyl/ Hemisphere

$$  S=2πr(k2r+h),\, V=πr^2(k h+4r^3) $$

$$ \frac{S_r}{S_h} =\frac{V_r}{V_h} \rightarrow k =2r/h $$